# AWS SDK for PHP - How to get creation date of a file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have working code which returns all the files under s3 bucket. I have to get today's uploaded files for further processing.

Code to get files :

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials' => array(
    'key'    => 'XXXX',
    'secret' => 'YYYYYYYY'

)
));

$iterator = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',    
    'Prefix' => 'adityamusic',
    'Suffix' => '.xlsx',
    ), array(
    'limit'     => 999,
    'page_size' => 100
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    print_r($object['LastModified']); 
    print_r($object['LastModified']['date']);   //this gives error
}
```

`print_r($object['LastModified'])` outputs as :

```
Array
(
   [Key] => mymusic/
   [LastModified] => Aws\Api\DateTimeResult Object
       (
           [date] => 2016-08-03 06:20:31
           [timezone_type] => 2
           [timezone] => Z
       )

   [ETag] => "sadfasdf2342"
   [Size] => 0
   [StorageClass] => STANDARD
   [Owner] => Array
       (
           [DisplayName] => test
           [ID] => asdfasdfasdf
       )

)
```

I am not able to access date key.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`LastModified` is an instance of `Aws\Api\DateTimeResult` class, since  `DateTimeResult` extends `\DateTime` object, just use `format` method as you would normally do when working with standard DateTime objects.

`echo $object['LastModified']->format(\DateTime::ISO8601)`

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for more formatting options.

P.S. `$object['LastModified']->date` will not work because its not designed to be accessed [directly](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382).